# Monitoring progress of a SQL script with many UPDATEs in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb, database-table, autocommit

I'm running a script with several million update statements like this:

```
UPDATE data SET value = 0.9234 WHERE fId = 47616 AND modDate = '2018-09-24'  AND valueDate = '2007-09-01'  AND last_updated < '2018-10-01';
```

fId, modDate and valueDate are the 3 components of the data table's composite primary key.

I initially ran this with `AUTOCOMMIT=1` but I figured it would speed up if I set `AUTOCOMMIT=0` and wrapped the transactions into blocks of 25.

In autocommit mode, I used `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and I'd see the UPDATE statement in the output, so from the fId foreign key, I could tell how far the script had progressed.

However without autocommit, watching it running now, I haven't seen anything with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, just this:

```
610257  schema_owner_2  201.177.12.57:53673  mydb  Sleep   0               NULL                    0.000
611020  schema_owner_1  201.177.12.57:58904  mydb  Query   0       init    show processlist        0.000
```

The `Sleep` status makes me paranoid that other users on the system are blocking the updates, but if I run `SHOW OPEN TABLES` I'm not sure whether there's a problem:

```
MariaDB [mydb]> SHOW OPEN TABLES;
+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table          | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+
| mydb     | data           |      2 |           0 |
| mydb     | forecast       |      1 |           0 |
| mydb     | modification   |      0 |           0 |
| mydb     | data3          |      0 |           0 |
+----------+----------------+--------+-------------+
```

Is my script going to wait forever? Should I go back to using autocommit mode? Is there any way to see how far it's progressed? I guess I can inspect the data for the updates but that would be laborious to put together.

Comment: Sleep just means the user is idle, it won't block the updates. Generally `autocommit=1` is fine. In `autocommit=0`, have you checked that the updates are actually happening? If nothing is showing in the processlist while you're running the script there might be something wrong with the script statements.

Comment: I have noticed that an error in a previous script didn't cause the script to fail immediately - in fact, I think it was hours before it failed. But it is difficult to check, although I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check for progress by actually checking the data.
- I assume you are doing `COMMIT`?
- It is reasonable to see nothing -- each `UPDATE` will take very few milliseconds; there will be `Sleep` time between `UPDATEs`.
- `Time` being `0` is your clue that it is progressing.
- There won't necessarily be any clue in the `PROCESSLIST` of how far it has gotten.
- You could add `SELECT SLEEP(1), $fid;` in the loop, where $fid (or whatever) is the last `UPDATEd` row id.  That would slow down the progress by 1 second per 25 rows, so maybe you should do groups of 100 or 500.